# NSolve doesn't compute with NIntegrate, just repeats input

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

First, I searched for similar questions but none of them helped me. I suppose that my problem has to do with a `NIntegrate` inside a `NSolve`, but I'm not sure. I am trying to find values of some parameter where a numerical integration (as a function of m) equals another given function of m. Both the numerical integration and the other function are well defined and return the right values when evaluated separately, but I can't find when they are equal with the `NSolve`. I tried using `FindRoot` as well; it finds a solution, but it isn't really what I need. The code is the following:

```
ψ1[t_, m_] := Sqrt[m/(m - 1/2)] JacobiCN[t/Sqrt[m - 1/2], m];

dψ1[t_, m_] := -Sqrt[m]/(m - 1/2) JacobiSN[t/Sqrt[m - 1/2], m] JacobiDN[
    t/Sqrt[m - 1/2], m];

T1[m_] := 4 Sqrt[m - 1/2] EllipticK[m];

om11[t_, m_] := 
  2 Root[14641 - 242 dψ1[t, m]^2 + 5203 ψ1[t, m]^2 - 
      66 dψ1[t, m]^2 ψ1[t, m]^2 + 847 ψ1[t, m]^4 + 
      45 ψ1[t, m]^6 + (-5324 + 44 dψ1[t, m]^2 - 
         1672 ψ1[t, m]^2 + 6 dψ1[t, m]^2 ψ1[t, m]^2 - 
         198 ψ1[t, m]^4 - 6 ψ1[t, m]^6) #1 + (726 - 
         2 dψ1[t, m]^2 + 175 ψ1[t, m]^2 + 
         11 ψ1[t, m]^4) #1^2 + (-44 - 
         6 ψ1[t, m]^2) #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1];

ωbar11[m_] := 
  Sqrt[NIntegrate[om11[t, m], {t, 0, T1[m]}]/T1[m]];

Ω1[m_] := Pi/(2 Sqrt[m - 1/2] EllipticK[m]);

    res11[lmax_] := 
      Table[Flatten[
   NSolve[l Ω1[m]/2 == ωbar11[m] && 0.5 < m < 1, 
    m, Reals]], {l, 1, lmax}];

    plres11[lmax_] := 
      Graphics[{Red, Line[{{Sqrt[m], -1/2}, {Sqrt[m], 1/2}}]}] /. 
       res11[lmax];
```

I didn't use plres11 yet because I want to compute res11 first.

Even when I just run

```
NSolve[Ω1[m]/2 == ωbar11[m] && 
  0.5 < m < 1, m, Reals]
```

it only returns

```
NSolve[π/(4 Sqrt[-(1/2) + m] EllipticK[m]) == 
   1/2 Sqrt[NIntegrate[om11[t, m], {t, 0, T1[m]}]/(
    Sqrt[-(1/2) + m] EllipticK[m])] && 0.5 < m < 1, m, Reals]
```

that is basically the input... I am kinda new to Mathematica, so I'm accepting any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Try `FindRoot`. `NSolve`/`NIntegrate` was not designed to work with `NIntegrate` depending on a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all the input arguments in your functions to `_?NumericQ`, examplary `T1[m__?NumericQ]:=..`.

Additionally change the definition

```
\[Omega]bar11[m_?NumericQ] :=Module[{t}, Sqrt[NIntegrate[om11[t, m], {t, 0,T1[m]}]/T1[m]]]
```

I don't know why Mathematica isn't able to solve the equation `res11` using `NDSolve, FindRoot`

As a workaround evaluate the equation `l \[CapitalOmega]1[m]/2 == \[Omega]bar11[m]` for `l` pointwise

```
ml = Table[{m, \[Omega]bar11[m]/(\[CapitalOmega]1[m]/2)} , {m,Range[.5 + #, 1 - #, #] &[.02]}]

ListPlot[ml, GridLines -> {None, Range[15 ]},AxesLabel -> {m, l[m]}]
```

[image]

and solve interpolation for `l`

```
res11[lmax_] :=Table[{m, l} /. 
 FindRoot[Interpolation[ml][m] == l, {m, .9, .5, 1}], {l,Range[lmax ] // Reverse}] // Quiet // Chop

res11[15]
(*{{0.53557, 1}, {0.559109, 2}, {0.621186,3}, {0.67386, 4}, {0.730756,5}, 
{0.786818, 6},{0.837974, 7}, {0.88157,8}, {0.916492,9}, {0.943022, 10}, 
{0.961924, 11}, {0.974901,12}, {0.984756,13}, {0.992774, 14}, {0.999589, 15}}*)
```

The results might be improved if necessary using `FindRoot` with res11[...] as starting values (long evaluation time 10minutes!) :

```
Table[{m , mli[[2]]} /.FindRoot[ \[Omega]bar11[m] == mli[[2]] \[CapitalOmega]1[m]/2, {m  ,If[mli[[2]] == 1, 0.55, mli[[1]] ],1/2,1}] , {mli, res11[15] }]
```

Hope it helps!